# Is it more fuel efficient to transport gear in a low or high efficiency vehicle?

Tags: fuel-consumption, efficiency, engine-load

Let's say I have two vehicles that are driving to the same destination from the same origin with the same driving style along the way.  One is a larger SUV vehicle and the other is a smaller more efficient vehicle.  I have cargo that I can transport in either vehicle but I'm not sure which vehicle it's better to load for maximum overall fuel efficiency.

Intuitively I thought it would be better to load it in the more efficient vehicle, but I realized that the smaller and more efficient vehicle may actually suffer in terms of efficiency more than the larger vehicle.

Which car should I load the cargo into?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not really sure this is answerable, because there are still so many variables. The big one is, can the more "fuel efficient" vehicle actually haul the load you're talking about. It depends on the amount of load, what the initial fuel economy was for each, how you are planning on hauling whatever you're hauling (inside the vehicle, towed, on the roof, etc). It all plays into the scheme of it.